# Why Tomcat Server do not Change name of a copied JSF Project

Tags: java, jsf, tomcat

In the Eclipse IDE, i copied and pasted a JSF project. Renamed the project and changed its Context Root in the Project > Properties to the newly given name for the application but when i run the two application (the original and the copied) the Tomcat Server shows same name for both the applications (the one that original application had) even for the newly copied application? and this creates problems some times too?
   What am i doing wrong.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

- Right click project, select webcontent, set new context root, Click ok
- Clean the current project
- right click on tomcat from server view, select add and remove, remove the project and again right click on tomcat and click on clean
- refresh the project and then do *run on server*

Comment: You mean Right Click>Properties>Web Content Settings and Give a new name? i did that prior to this post but to no avail. I deleted server, and then added fresh server, but when i try to add project, both the projects appear with the same name again...

Comment: and then you followed rest of steps ?